# Show that a language is not decidable by reducing from ATM

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, halting-problem

Let (ATM denotes the language $\{\langle M,w \rangle \mid \text{TM $M$ accepts $w$}\}$)
show that the language L={<M1,M2,w> | M1 and M2 both accept or reject w} is undecidable by reducing 
ATM to L
Not really sure how to approach this. Any hints or pointers

Comment: What happens when $M_1$ is the Turing Machine that immediately accepts?

Comment: Give a computable function $f$ from $\langle M,w \rangle$ to $\langle M_1,M_2,w \rangle$ such that $\langle M,w \rangle$ accepts if and only if $f(\langle M,w \rangle)$ accepts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to define $M'$ that would accept $\iff$ both $M_1$ and $M_2$ accepted or rejected (together)